# Toggle a Function Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to toggle show/hide value to my button, tried alot but nothing worked. Here is my cide. Thanks in Advance.

```
function SLIDE_HIDE(SLIDEID){
    $("#"+SLIDEID).prop('value', 'HIDE');
    $("#"+SLIDEID).prop('value', 'SHOW');
}
```

HTML/PHP Code

```
<input id=\"$OPID\" onclick='SLIDE_HIDE($OPID);' class=\"slidehide\" type=\"button\" value=\"HIDE\" >
```

Comment: that was just my example bro, a pseudo

Answer (score 0):

if what you're asking for is how to toggle back and forth using the code you provided, then do something like this:

```
function SLIDE_HIDE(SLIDEID)
{
    if ($('#' + SLIDEID).prop('value').toUpperCase() == "SHOW") {
        $("#"+SLIDEID).prop('value', 'HIDE');
    } else {
        $("#"+SLIDEID).prop('value', 'SHOW');
    }
}
```

if you're looking for a way to do it because .prop isnt actually setting the button value:

did  you try .attr or .val?

Not really sure what you want to do by the question, but either of the below may work.  Also, this probably is obvious, but you can't run both lines back to back as they are in your example or it will always end up as "SHOW".

```
$("#"+SLIDEID).attr('value','show');
// or
$("#"+SLIDEID).val('show');
```

and of course

```
$("#"+SLIDEID).attr('value','hide');
// or
$("#"+SLIDEID).val('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#"+SLIDEID).val(function(i,oldVal) {
    return oldVal === "HIDE" ? "SHOW" : "HIDE";
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5SBj/2/

Note that if your PHP variable `$OPID` is a string then you'd need to put it in quotes when passing it, like this: `onclick='SLIDE_HIDE(\"$OPID\");'`

The [`.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value) accepts a function as an argument, where jQuery will call that function passing the old value of the element and then set the value to whatever you return from the function.

Note that if your element can be selected by the class `"slidehide"` you can remove the inline `onclick="..."` attribute an assign a handler with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slidehide").click(function() {
        $(this).val(function(i,oldVal) {
           return oldVal === "HIDE" ? "SHOW" : "HIDE";
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5SBj/

(The document ready wrapper isn't needed if you include the script at the end of the body.)

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't check the old value. Try running an if/else statement in your function to check the current value and set it to the opposite. Example: if it has a value of "HIDE", then set it to "SHOW". If it has a value of "SHOW" then set it to "HIDE".